# Setting up Remote Access over a home network?

Tags: wireless, networking, remote-desktop, remote-access

So I have two computers; one desktop and one laptop. Both of these computers are running Ubuntu 11.10, and both are connected to the same wireless network. What I want to do is set things up to where I can use my laptop to remote access my desktop, from another room. I don't need to be able to access it away from home, just to be able to control my desktop while sitting on the couch in another room.

Since I'm fairly new to Linux, I have pretty much no idea how to go about setting this up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you Using DHCP To Connect to Wireless Network ?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu includes VNC server and client

Search for Desktop

[image]

The configuration dialog looks like this

[image]

**Be sure to use a strong password and disable UPNP on your router.**

Connect with the viewer using your ip address.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After setting up the server (following bodhi.zazen screenshots).
Install remmina and give it a try ( imho the best client i've found so far ).

**sudo apt-get install remmina**

Remmina supports VNC, RDP, ssh, so you will be able to control Windows machines via RDP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answers above are correct but i will try to make them easier for new ubuntu users.my ubuntu version is 18.04.1 Lts . to check youyr ubuntu version **try to open your settings -> then go to details.**

**first step activate sharing on our desktop:**
**under settings** ->**select sharing** and **click on the large button screen sharing**
you will have a popup windows under that windows make sure to select the option **Allow connections to control my screen**.
under , you have to kind of access method.I recommend to select **require password** and to specify a password that you will use to connect to your desktop.Please under networks section , enable the network shared between the two equipments.

**second step connect to your desktop from your laptop** ubuntu comes with Remmina (if not available under Activities -> search Remmina , please install it) open remmina .You will see a "plus (+)" button to create new connection , please click on it .Enter any value for field **name** , you can leave the field group empty , for protocol select **(VNC -virtual network computing)**
under Basic , for network enter the IP address of your desktop.
you can fill anything for the field user name. on the field user passsword enter the password defined when sharing screen on your lapTop.For resolution field you can leave "use client resolution" selected.As color depth select (True color 24bpp) and finally for quality you can select medium.
Save all your modifications . The created connection should appear on remmina windows just do a right click and select connect. You will see your desktop screen  appearing.
**remarks:** your desktop firewall should be disable ( check it under your terminal with the command **ufw status** ) And be sure tne both equipments are connected through the same network . Hope this will be helpful for someone.